# Photon field transformation with charge conjugation in scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, quantum-electrodynamics

I am attempting problem 1 [in this problem sheet](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/AQFT/probs2.pdf). Consider scalar QED where the Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}=D_{\mu}\phi^*D^{\mu}\phi-m^2|\phi|^2-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
$$

we are requested that if a charge conjugation transformation swaps $\phi$ with $\phi^*$ to say how the photon field $A^{\mu}$ has to change. Seemingly straightforwardly I think I get
$$
\mathcal{L}=D_{\mu}\phi D^{\mu}\phi^*-m^2|\phi|^2-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
$$

so the Lagrangian does stay invariant and $A^{\mu}$ needs not change. Nonetheless, I have a feeling that I am being naive at some point, so, am I being naive? and if so where?

Comment: Be careful about how you write the Lagrangian. It should be $\mathcal{L} = (D_\mu \phi)^* D^\mu \phi - m^2 |\phi|^2-\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}$. Take it into account when answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $D_\mu \phi = \partial_\mu \phi + ie A_\mu \phi$,

and the swapping of $\phi$ to $\phi^*$ implies that

$D_\mu \phi = \partial_\mu \phi + ie A_\mu \phi\mapsto \partial_\mu \phi^* + ie A_\mu \phi^* \neq (D_\mu \phi)^*$

Requirement for having an invariant Action: $D_\mu \phi \mapsto (D_\mu \phi)^*$

This holds only if $A_\mu \mapsto -A_\mu$ (photon kinetic energy term remains also unchanged).